# Finding jar files for an eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Some years ago I wrote a simple plugin for eclipse that extends `org.eclipse.core.runtime.AbstractPlugin`.  It seems that every time I update eclipse to a new version of ecplise, classes like that one have migrated to some new .jar file.

For example, I found that `AbstractPlugin` is now in `org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.7....jar`. But then I find that its super class is not in the same jar, so I have to find out what .jar *it* is in and so on and so on.

So there is this laborious task of trying to find out what .jar files the all library classes that I use (and they use and so on and so on) are now in, and adjusting the list of external jars in the project's build path.

Sites such as 
   http://www.jarfinder.com
are useful (but often out of date).  And Java Search as shown in http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#eclipsesourcecode can help. But surely there is a better way.

What is the best way to keep a plugin's buildpath up to date as we migrate to new versions of eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, here is what I did:

- First on the dependencies tab of plugin.xml, I added all the packages I needed under "imported packages"
- Then I right-clicked on the project and selected PDE Tools >> Update Classpath ... , accepted the defaults and clicked on Finish.

That is much better as the plugin (presumably) now properly expresses what it needs to run.